# Invalid Column Name Error Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Firstly, I checked other answers in the website, but I couldn't find a solution. I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project which is EF code first. I have Is class, in this class I have this :

```
  [UIHint("YerGorme")]
  public virtual YerGorme IliskiliYerGorme { get; set; }
```

And in YerGorme class I have this :

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources), Name = "YerGorme_MahalindekiDegerlemeCinsi_Mahalindeki_Değerleme_Cinsi")]
public int MahalindekiCinsi { get; set; }
```

When I run the code I get this exception:

> Invalid column name 'MahalindekiCinsi'.

Can you tell me what to do to get rid of this exception? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using code first? Is the database already created and the column doesn't exist? Also, change the  g in Degerleme to a Latin g.

Comment: @Ted, Yes I'm using code first and database already created. I don't know if the column doesn't exist because I can't reach the db.

Comment: What do you mean can't reach the dB? Open server explorer in visual studio and check the SQL server that your connection string refers to.

Comment: use `YerGorme_MahalindekiDegerlemeCinsi_Mahalindeki_Değerleme_Cinsi` instead of 'MahalindekiCinsi '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use Ğ for column name.